# fs.readDirSync can't find dir in typescript?

Tags: node.js, fs

This is a very simple which i expected to work from js:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
var testDir = './tests';

// Add each .js file to the mocha instance
fs.readdirSync(testDir)
  .filter(function(file) {
    // Only keep the .js files
    return file.substr(-3) === '.js';
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    mochaInstance.addFile(path.join(testDir, file));
  });
```

I am running the transpiled version of this code but this throws an error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './tests'
>       at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:783:3)

how do i fix this? I am certain that the directory for the files './tests' is correct, my node version is v10.13.0

Comment: standard functions don't know the relative path so it is recommended to use `__dirname + '/tests'` or else you can use `path`

Comment: Are you only transpiling?  Or are you also packaging?  Is any of your code messing with the current directory because `./` is relative to the current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use __dirname which is a global variable in Node.js that gets the current directory of your application. Combined with path you could end up using something like this:

```
mochaInstance.addFile(path.join(__dirname, testDir, file));
```

Comment: `__dirname` is not actually a global variable.  It's a module variable that has a potentially different value in each module.